# When awaiting Task.Run for a compute bound operation, is the awaiting using a IOCP?

Tags: c#, async-await

I understand overlapped IO for things you do through IO, like sending a SQL Query or a HTTP request. So when doing `await http.GetAsync(url)` I imagine that the internals has queued an overlapped IO operation and my execution will continue when the ICOP is signalled.

However, when we are running something that is purely compute bound in a thread pool worker thread, like `await Task.Run(() => CalculatePrimeNumbersFirst(n))`, is the thread calling `Task.Run` actually blocked because there is not actual IOCP registered?

I think that callback I executed in the thread pool with signal the awaiter and continue the execution it self, but I could not find a good explanation about this.

Comment: The whole point of `await` is to *avoid* blocking.

Comment: The async and await pattern and the TPL in general is a little more complex than what is likely to be offered in an answer to this sort of question. I would suggest looking up Stephen Clearys and Stephen Toubs blogs and jump in the deep end. They are both very well read, and the pseudo authorities on all things taskey.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `await Task.Run(() => CpuOperations())` will just pick an idle thread from the pool and execute your delegate from within.

Then, the execution will simply notify the `await`'s state machine of its completion, and the chosen synchronization context will continue to execute your next line of code.

No actual IO ports will be awaited and/or used.